# CanCan ability in ActiveAdmin for batch_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, cancancan

Let's say I want to let some user to read, create and delete(with batch_action) their posts, but I don't want to let them to update posts.
Something like this:

```
   can [:read, :create, :destroy], Post
```

But when I am running batch action I am seeing that cancan adds some awkward condition like

```
   [WHERE 1=0]
```

When I am using :manage instead of solo crud operations(:read, :update, :create, :destroy) it works good.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe you can look at this docs to add a condition to your batch_action: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/9-batch-actions.md#conditional-display

Answer (score 0):

You must add `batch_action` as a possible action the user can do on Post

`can %i[read create destroy batch_action], Post`